# Copy a column of formulas to a closed workbook in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of data into Excel files.
There are about 174 files. Each is named Book2.xslx through Book174.xlsx

I have a master document where I have a column of formulas that I would like to paste (or insert) into each of these spreadsheets without having to actually open each one individually.

Does someone know any code I can use to do this?

As an example, I would say I would want to copy the range P:P - the whole of column P - and insert it or paste it into Column P in the closed workbooks.

Can this be done? If it works , and I want to insert different ranges and cells every time I wanted something different inserted or pasted? Or is there a macro for example, that I could run , that would copy what I've selected to the same place in every unopened spreadsheet named Book*.xlsx?

Comment: Kindly show us your code ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: is there are reason why you do not want to open the files? If you want to automate the copy-paste process you can open the files with `visibility` set to `false` so your eyes do not even notice it when a macro is running on another file. Another approach is using ADO.

Comment: @mehow you cannot write to XL files uisng ADO as the driver is READ ONLY and the Object Model isn't available.

Comment: @manny have you tried using the macro recorder to get some code, then used your vba coding skills to modify it with a loop etc?

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot do this on existing files without opening them** (whether in Excel, or using FSO, as the *Object Model won't be available to apply to those files*

having said that, it is possible to automate the modifications using VBA.

If you would post your code, we can help you improve it or resolve any issues with bugs or performance